# cat files using incremental values

Tags: macos, merge, terminal, cat

I am trying to merge files using cat (MacOS via terminal), but am wondering how I might do so incrementally. This is what I am doing at present:

```
cat file004_*_3401_*.txt > 3401.txt
```

This merges all the files labeled with 3401. There are hundreds of files, labelled from 3401 upwards. As it stands I am just changing the number each time, but is there a way to cat all the filenames containing 3401, then move to 3402 etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the bash shell you could do this in a shell script. Something like this should work:

```
for i in 1002 .. 1006

do

cat *$i*.txt > $i.txt
done
```

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS. Also is the wrong way to do it. mp3wrap is suggested to be used. This batch creates a huge mp3 file like 500 GB big.